# Update content in shown dialog

Tags: android, dialog

Is it possible to update the content (e.g. a text) in a custom dialog when it is already shown? Or do I need to close and recreate it?

If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, the Progress Dialog does it for instance.

To do it with a custom dialog you will essentially need to have a updateHandler which you can invoke from some other part of your code, like a button or a thread, whatever. You'll need to get and keep a reference to the textview you want to update. In your updateHandler just call setText on your textview to update it.

It should be quite straightforward. I don't have any example code sorry, but you might be able to Google for some.

Comment: How can I do it with a custom dialog?